# limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fractions, products, telescopic-series

I know from my intuition that the sequence

$$x_n=\left(1-\cfrac{1}{3}\right)^2 \left(1-\cfrac{1}{6}\right)^2 \left(1-\cfrac{1}{10}\right)^2\cdots \cdots\left(1-\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}}\right)^2,\quad n\geq2$$

is convergent. 
But i don't know how to prove it.I almost try to apply every theorem I know (for eg ratio  test ,monotone convergence theorem,...). Help me to prove this.

Proof or idea is needed.Where does the sequence converge to?

Comment: are you sure sir

Comment: hm let me Control this

Comment: no i was wrong sorry

Comment: i think it would be zero or some simple fraction like 1/3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{2}{k(k+1)}\right)=\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{(k+2)(k-1)}{k(k+1)}=$$
$$\frac{4\cdot1}{2\cdot3}\cdot\frac{5\cdot2}{3\cdot4}\cdot\frac{6\cdot3}{4\cdot5}\cdot...\cdot\frac{n(n-3)}{(n-2)(n-1)}\cdot\frac{(n+1)(n-2)}{(n-1)n}\cdot\frac{(n+2)(n-1)}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n+2}{3n}$$

Comment: i think a square is missing

Comment: Squaring it's for you, dear doctor.

Comment: i have already squared

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg very thanks.....now i am clear with telescoping series

Answer (score 11):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=2}^\infty\left(1-\frac2{k^2+k}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{\color{#C00}{(k-1)}\color{#090}{(k+2)}}{\color{#00F}{k}\color{#C90}{(k+1)}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\color{#C00}{(n-1)!}\,\color{#090}{(n+2)!/3!}}{\color{#00F}{n!/1!}\,\color{#C90}{(n+1)!/2!}}\\[3pt]
&=\frac13\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+2}{n}\\[3pt]
&=\frac13
\end{align}
$$
Your product is just the square of this one.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$1-\dfrac2{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{n^2+n-2}{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{(n+2)(n-1)}{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{n-1}n}{\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}}=\dfrac{f(n-1)}{f(n+1)}$$

where $f(m)=\dfrac m{m+1}$

See [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100299/how-do-telescopic-series-work-in-general-and-in-this-specific-problem  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475256/if-this-is-a-telescoping-series-then-how-does-it-collapse-frac3r1rr-1r/475264  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353396/calculate-sum-limits-n-geq-1-frac112-ldotsn/2353400#2353400

Comment: could you please explain more sir

Comment: @SathasivamK, Please set a few values of $n$ starting from $2$ to check the surviving terms of the product

Answer (score 1):

prove by induction that for your sum is hold $$\frac{(n+2)^2}{9n^2}$$

Comment: sir please give some more hint sir....i'm approaching

Comment: yes sir the limit should be 1/9...but please give a one more small hint...I will finish it sir

Comment: i think you can find enough hints