# sum over $x_{n;k_1,k_2,k_3\dots k_{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I saw a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353542/limit-of-a-sequence), and then I thought,

Let's take $$x_{n;k_1,k_2,k_3\dots k_{n-1}}=\Big(1-\frac{k_1}{3}\Big)^2\Big(1-\frac{k_2}{6}\Big)^2\Big(1-\frac{k_3}{10}\Big)^2\dots \Big(1-\frac{k_{n-1}}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\Big)^2\space n\geq2\\k_1\leq2,k_2\leq 3,\dots k_{n-1}\leq n.$$

What is $$S_n=\sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3,\dots k_{n-1}}x_{n;k_1,k_2,k_3\dots k_{n-1}}$$

or where is it going asymptotically?

So $\Big(1-\frac{k_{m-1}}{\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}\Big)=\frac{1+2+\dots +m-k_{m-1}}{1+2+\dots +m}$. But what next?